# Making a PHP server to read a java based client

Tags: java, php, sockets, connection

```
public class Client {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket sock = new Socket();
    sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 43594));

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

    out.writeByte(255);
    out.writeLong(133713371337L);

    System.out.println("Response: " + in.readByte() + ", " + in.readLong());

    sock.close();
}
```

and the PHP server meant to read and write back to the java client:

```
<?php
require 'Stream.php';
$stream = new Stream();

$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 43594;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, 0, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');
socket_listen($sock);
echo "Server listening on port " . $port . "...";
$client = socket_accept($sock);

$data = socket_read($client, 1, PHP_BINARY_READ);
$byte_array = unpack('C*', $data);
$stream->setStream($byte_array);
$b2 = $stream->readUnsignedByte();

$l1 = socket_read($client, $stream->readQWord());
echo $b1 . " " . $l1;
socket_write($client, 0);
socket_write($client, $stream->writeQWord(2148000000));
```

The stream class being used: http://pastebin.com/p1vc9aPG

I'm trying to write a client in java that contacts, sends and reads data to/from the server. The server is written in PHP and ran via cli, while the client is written in java. Please help if you can, there probably aren't many people who can help with this issue.

The protocol is already established and I'm just trying to implement it in PHP. I can't seem to read/write back to the java client from the PHP page.

The client side in Java is defined how I want it to be. What I'm looking for is the equivalent server in PHP and I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: In the end it is all a stream of data read from/written to the network. So the fact that the languages are different does not make it "strange" at all.

Comment: So, can you write an example of how I would read the byte & long sent from the java client on the PHP server?

Comment: As I point out below, use a common protocol, not a Java specific one.

Comment: You might look into Quercus, which is a Java server that can run PHP inside it. You can call java code from PHP as if it was native PHP functions. You can then have java talk to talk to java, but process in PHP.

Comment: Perhaps implement a SoapServer in PHP side: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php

Comment: I don't see any fatal flaws, although I see some small mistakes that I'm sure some standard debugging will uncover for you. But, have you ever heard of [Apache Thrift](http://projects.apache.org/projects/thrift.html)? If the goal is really to communicate between java and php, you don't need to write this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually written this the other way around, the client was a PHP web app and the server was a java daemon under jsvc.

The first consideration should be defining a transfer protocol, since the types and object representations of the two languages are different and they might be running on hardware with different numeric representations.  I'd recommend JSON or XML.

After that your server probably needs to be able to handle multiple connections, so threading or non-blocking socket I/O will be needed.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really help.

Comment: The point is that the Java Data Stream and Object Stream protocols are not appropriate for communication with PHP, you should use a common protocol such as JSON.

Comment: So theres no way to just communicate using a data steam with PHP? That's exactly what I'm trying to do. The protocol is already established.

Comment: You might look at Apache Thrift http://thrift.apache.org/ it claims to provide cross language transport for Java, PHP and several other languages.

Comment: The client side in Java is defined how I want it to be. What I'm looking for is the equivalent server in PHP and I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Why not write he server in Java? it's a much better choice as a server language.

Comment: Because that's not what I'm writing.  This project is purely for POC and I really don't know if it's even possible.

Comment: It's possible, just a lot of work.  You need to get the definition of how Java encodes Data streams and then start coding an equivalent in PHP, a network sniffer like tcpdump or snoop will help as well so you can see what is going over the network.

Comment: So I can't just do: socket_write(); and socket_read(); to read/write data to the server?

Comment: You will have to interpret the stream of data that you get from Java, your stream class looks to be already doing the byte order stuff.  And then you need to create a stream that Java can read. You should start a new post on Java Data Streams in PHP after you have done some more research.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should call `.flush()` after you write to the socket in your Java code. The data won't get sent to the server otherwise.

Then, communications between network endpoints is just about agreement on the protocol used. There is nothing language specific here...

Comment: The protocol is already established, I'm just trying to implement it into PHP.

Comment: DataOutputStreams and socket output streams don't need flushing. They aren't buffered.

Comment: @EJP that is not my experience

Comment: @fge It is your experience when there is a BufferedOutputStream in the stack. Not otherwise.